# questionnaire (audit) class diagram?

Tags: uml

i'm working on a web application using JSF2,spring and jpa,and my application allow users to :

- create new audits
- answering audit's related questions

...

the rules for my class diagram are :

- 1. a question belongs to one chapter
- 2. a chapter has many questions.
- 3. an audit has 1 or many chapters
- 4. a chapter could be used in one or multiple audits
- 5. a question (that belongs to a chapter ) has one answer for iche audit.

in my class diagram i have associated the AUDIT Class with the QUESTION Class so as to generated an Association Class called "ANSWER" which has the answer attribue.

im not shure if that's correct,or if i should do that with an other way.
any ideas ?
(sorry about my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave very little information to work with. This is the best that I can do without detailed description how the model is going to be used:

[image: UML]

Comment: Thanks Sami for your answer, do you think it's allowed to have a loop (between classes) in a class diagram like you did,is it possible to do that ? what information you need?

Comment: There's no reason to avoid circular dependencies. Just be sure to use lazy loading, if you use ORM (such as JPA) to load entities.

Comment: Oki ,Thank you again,just one last thing that I didn't mention : once the audit is done an action plan that contains actions must be generated for all the questions with answer = "NO".                         So the ACTION Class well be associated with the ANSWER Class, and the ACTIONPLAN Class with the AUDIT Class, and lastly ACTION Class with ACTIONPLAN Class.                                                 just confused with the part actions are specified only for questions with answers = "NO",does this mean i need to add something?

Comment: Is there one or multiple Actions per question (= does each "no"-Answer generate an action, or is there just one for every question with one or more "no"-Answers)? What exactly is an Actionplan and what is its' relation with Audit?

Comment: there is one or mutiple actions for each answer 'NO',an audit could have many questions with answer 'NO' and for each those questions (with answer="no") an action or mutliple actions must be specified. an action plan is defined for an audit after it is done and it contains the list of actions (specefied earlier for the "no" answers),and of course an audit can have only one actionplan and an action plan belongs to one audit. (the actionplan well simplify 
my db queries earlier because it will contain already the list of actions) does it seems correct to you? or we don't neet actionplan class.

Comment: You said that actionplan may contain one or multiple actions, but you didn't explain what action or actionplan actually are. I updated the model, but I can't do much more without further knowledge about the problem domain. When I do modelling I focus on getting the terminology and definitions right.